# How can I get sequences of actions from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, pattern-matching, combinations

I have a Pandas dataframe in Python in which is registered when Ramirez enters and leaves a building. I also have a list in which all events in the building are registrered, from turning on the lights to flushing a toilet or calling an elevator. I have ordered them chronollogically as:

```
Visit 1: C2, C4, C1 None, None
Visit 2: C2, C1, C2, None, None
Visit 3: C1, C3, C1, C2, C3
Visit 4: C1, C2, C3, None, None
```

and so on (this means that during Ramirez's first visit, first happened C2, the C4 and then C1).

I want to find out what are the events that Ramirez is responsible for. To do that I want to find the most common sequences in the data.
For example, C1, C2 appaears during his second, third and fourth visits. C2, C3 occur during his third and fourth visits.

I need a program to obtain the chains of events ordered from the most common to the less common, also, C1, C1 or any other pair like that shoul be ignored.

I would like some advice on how to obtain this code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this input:

```
          0   1   2     3     4
Visit 1  C2  C4  C1  None  None
Visit 2  C2  C1  C2  None  None
Visit 3  C1  C3  C1    C2    C3
Visit 4  C1  C2  C3  None  None
```

You need to iterate over the rows and pairs of successive values. The most efficient will be to use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from itertools import pairwise
from collections import Counter

out = Counter(p for _, s in df.T.items() for p in pairwise(s.dropna()))

s = pd.Series(out, name='counts')
```

Output:

```
# out
Counter({('C1', 'C2'): 3,
         ('C2', 'C3'): 2,
         ('C2', 'C4'): 1,
         ('C4', 'C1'): 1,
         ('C2', 'C1'): 1,
         ('C1', 'C3'): 1,
         ('C3', 'C1'): 1})

# s
C2  C4    1
C4  C1    1
C2  C1    1
C1  C2    3
    C3    1
C3  C1    1
C2  C3    2
Name: counts, dtype: int64
```

The pure pandas equivalent would be [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the stacked DataFrame and its [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) self, then [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)+[`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html):

```
s = df.stack()
out = (pd.concat([s.groupby(level=0).shift(), s], axis=1)
         .dropna().value_counts()
      )
```

Output:

```
0   1 
C1  C2    3
C2  C3    2
C1  C3    1
C2  C1    1
    C4    1
C3  C1    1
C4  C1    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```